# Flutter display gif from Uint8List

Tags: flutter, gif, mobile-development, uint8list

I need to display gif in my Flutter application. From the backend I get the gif as an Uint8List list from the response. Can you help me please how can I display this in the screen?

My code is here:

```
widget.session
        .get('/api/caff/getCaff/' + widget.gifId.toString())
        .then((response) async {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Uint8List bytes = response.bodyBytes;
        _gifFile = File.fromRawPath(bytes); // tried this but didn't work
      } else {
        CaffToast.showError(
            'Something went wrong! Please check your network connection!');
      }
    });
```

And I tried to display it as a file image but it didnt work:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          _gifFile == null ? Container() : Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: FileImage(_gifFile!))),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Do you have any suggestions how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to write your data to a file. The image data is already in memory so just display it. Just use a `MemoryImage` image provider instead

I'm not sure how you're getting the data from your network call to your `build` method so I'm using placeholders, but just do it the same was that you did when you were using a file.

```dart
_bytes = response.bodyBytes;
```

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          _gifFile == null ? Container() : Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: MemoryImage(_bytes!))),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it made the display more simple, but the problem was that the container didn't have a size and the default was 0 height. I edited the containers size so now it is working.

Comment: @BenceKovács Regardless, this method is far more efficient as you're no longer doing file IO.